# ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE for invoke chaincode request even when sufficient endorsements are successful

Tags: sdk, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

My network consists of 2 organizations with 2 peers each, 1 CA (for each org), 1 solo orderer.

I installed the chaincode on all peers and instantiated with endorsement policy `"AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"` through CLI.

I used this command for instantiation on `peer0.org1.example.com`

`peer chaincode instantiate -C mychannel -n mycc -P "AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"`

Now when I am trying to do invoke request through node SDK I am getting all successful endorsement responses but `ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE` error after sending to orderer.

I checked the received endorsements through `sendTransactionProposal` by using channel functions `verifyProposalResponse` and `compareProposalResponseResults`.

There is no extra information provided in `peer` and `orderer` logs to debug this error. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using `Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.1` and `node sdk v1.0.0` for running these tests.

Answer (score 0):

**verifyProposalResponse** and **compareProposalResponseResults** do not verify that enough endorsements are present or not.

> compareProposalResponseResults - Utility method to examine a set of proposals to check they contain the same endorsement result write sets. This will validate that the endorsing peers all agree on the result of the chaincode execution.

It will check if all proposal responses contain exactly the same response. Say your chaincode is supposed to return a value X. It verifies if all proposal responses contain X and nothing else. This is a valuable method to ensure that you don't have mismatch in read-write sets.

> verifyProposalResponse - Utility method to verify a single proposal response. It checks the following aspects:
>   1. The endorser's identity belongs to a legitimate MSP of the channel and can be successfully deserialized
>   2. The endorsement signature can be successfully verified with the endorser's identity certificate.

So you need to check that whether you are getting enough responses from the peers. Although there is no direct method to do it. You can try out a few ways:

1. Count the length of proposalResponses array
2. Manually inspect the MSP id of each proposal response (by converting the proposal responses to string)
3. As a preventive measure, add all the peers in the channel object and let the SDK do the job of sending it automatically to all the peers in the channel. This is done by not setting the **targets** in your **sendTransactionProposal**'s **ChaincodeInvokeRequest** object. [Refer : https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/global.html#ChaincodeInvokeRequest]

Comment: I have tried before all the three ways you suggested but I am still getting the same error